# Why is my If statement returning #VALUE?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a portion of code that trims a word from a cell that may contain multiple words. It then places this single word into another cell. Sometimes the cell which contains multiple words contains only one word, so when it trims, I get #VALUE! returned in the cell.

I will get the same returned value if it tried to trim a blank space which in this case is "_______________". It evaluates the cell looking for #VALUE!, and if it exists, checks the cell containing multiple words to see if the reason is because it is blank "________________" or is a single word.

I have used this code below to accomplish this but it is now ignoring the AND portion of the code and immediately performs the action if the cell reads #VALUE! regardless of the second condition.

Does anyone know what may cause this?

```
'Trims the full name
    Cells(i + 2, 10).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(RC[10],FIND(""/"",RC[10])-0,LEN(RC[10]),""""),"" "",REPT("" "",255)),255))"

    'Replaces Error with a blank ***Sometimes there are no defect 2 defects which causes this error
If Cells(i + 2, 10) = "#VALUE!" And Cells(i + 2, 20) = "________________________________________________________________________________" Then
Cells(i + 2, 10) = ""
Else
End If

'Replaces Error with a blank ***Sometimes there are no defect 3 which causes this error
If Cells(i + 2, 10) = "#VALUE!" Then
Cells(i + 2, 10) = Cells(i + 2, 20)
Else
End If
```

Comment: `iserror` may be of assistance

Comment: Seems to me this is an XY problem. You're jumping through hoops to solve Y (the #VALUE/___ issue) caused by not handling the X (TRIM) situation correctly. Are the *words* in the cell separated by `/`? If so, then instead of jumping directly to calling TRIM, use InStr first to see if the separator exists, and do one thing if it does and something else if it does not. That removes #VALUE from being an issue at all.

Comment: Why do `REPT(" ",255)` if you're going to `TRIM` the result anyway?

Comment: Ultimately, if you are looking to get a particular word separated by some delimiter character it's much more efficient in vba to just do something like `myWord = Split(Range("A1"), "/")(0)` That (0) tells it to return the first word, the second word would be `(1)`. This way you don't have to rely on really ugly formulas and all the processing that comes with it. Perhaps if you could share some sample data and your desired results we could help with a rewrite that isn't so cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

#### Formula

Not sure why you need to treat a series of underscores as a blank value when `vbNullString` or `""` would normally do a much cleaner job; assuming we're stuck with these underscores, I'd start by eliminating them with `SUBSTITUTE(<range>,"_","")`, and work off that - if the cell only contained underscores, the result of that function would be an empty string.

So a predicate like `LEN(SUBSTITUTE(<range>,"_",""))=0` would tell us if we're looking at a `<range>` that needs to be considered as empty.

Therefore `IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(<range>,"_",""))=0, <value if empty>, <value if not empty>)` would be a "skeleton" formula to build on IMO, unless I'm missing something (which is rather likely).

---

#### #VALUE!

A `#VALUE!` cell error isn't a string that says `"#VALUE!"` - it's an *error*, of type `Error`, and these can't be compared to a `String` literal (or anything for that matter).

So this statement is guaranteed to throw a *type mismatch* error if the cell actually contains an error:

```
If Cells(i + 2, 10) = "#VALUE!" Then
```

Which means you must have `On Error Resume Next` at the top of that snippet, which means your code is effectively ignoring run-time errors and happily running along in an error state - that's quite likely why the statements execute unconditionally.

Proof:

```
Sub test()
    On Error Resume Next
    If 12 / 0 > 1 And False Then ' throws error 11 "division by zero"
        Debug.Print "And False was ignored!" 'runs unconditionally
    End If
End Sub
```

Remove `On Error Resume Next`, it's not helping.

What you want is to verify whether the cell contains an error - use the `IsError` function for that:

```
If IsError(Cells(i + 2, 10)) Then
```

If you need to check *specifically* for `#VALUE!` error, you can do it like this:

```
If Cells(i + 2, 10).Value = CVErr(xlErrValue) Then
```

However that's kind of moot, because the `#VALUE!` error comes from the formula you've put in - use the `IFERROR` Excel function in your formula to provide a value in case of error:

```
=IFERROR(<formula>, <value to return formula results in an error>)
```

You could have your fallback value right there.

---

That said `String(n, "_")` would give you a string with `n` underscores. That would probably be much easier to debug than dealing with a string literal that *literally* has the `n` underscores in it. Much easier to do `String(80,"_")` than actually count the underscores and risk accidentally having 79 or 81.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting a formula in a cell by VBA, I would do this formula-work in your procedure itself.

```
With Cells(i + 2, 10)
    If InStr(.Offset(, 10).Value, "/") > 0 Then
       wrds = Split(Split(.Offset(, 10), "/")(0), " ")
       .Value = wrds(UBound(wrds))
    Else
      .Value = .Offset(, 10).Value 'or ""
    End If
End With
```

I assume these underscores are already eliminated